# validate line on custom sublist netsuite

Tags: netsuite

I have a before load user event script creating a custom sublist on a custom tab. I am pulling search results from a custom record into that sublist. The sublist is an inline editor type. Can I call validate line function on a field in the sublist? I can't seem to trigger any events for those fields inside the sublist.

Comment: I would suspect that you can. In your before record load you should be giving the sublist an id. I believe you can look for that in a client script. Is this on a standard record  (transaction, entity, item)? If so, why use the before record load to do this?

Comment: This is on an item record. I tried using the ID I gave the sublist and using a field change or a validate line function but nothing triggers. 
I am doing some verification of data upon save of the item record, and instead I wanted to do those checks upon hitting the add button on the sublist.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't build a custom sublist without the BRL code? It may make this easier and more efficient

Comment: Wouldn't that cause the standard inventory form to be customized? I can't modify the standard inventory part form. Also, I am searching across a custom record and only displaying the results of the specific item record I am currently on. So for example the custom record may have 10,000 lines but only 2 exists for this item. In the sublist I would only be showing the 2 results.

Comment: Are you not able to have a custom form? Why are you bound to only the standard form?  As for the search results, you would make the item (which I am assuming is on your custom record) in the available filters of your search. When you then use this search in the sublist, NetSuite effectively passes the item in as a parameter and filters the results for only that item. This would be more efficient because then the optimization can be done by NetSuite and you do not need to have a script do it. A script only really makes sense for this if you only want to add the list conditionally

Comment: Thanks for your help so far! Really appreciated! So I created the sublist on the item record just as you stated above. The issue is we can't modify the list. So when I create the fields and sublists through the before load event I can set that as an inline editor so users can add to the list. I need to have users add/modify/remove right there from the sub list. I do checks after that to verify what the user entered is valid etc. then update the custom record on save.

Comment: Is the search available to public? And on the search  (not the sublist but just running the search), you should be able to mark it as inline editable. If you can edit it there you should be able to in the sublist.

Comment: The search is public. I thought the same thing and made the search inline editable but I still cannot edit the sub list.

Comment: It's strange because I can access all of the fields in the sub list  in my before submit function that validates the data. I just can't use any field change or validate line functions.

Comment: I'm sorry Mike. I don't know. I really expected that to work. You may want to report it to NetSuite as a bug and see what they say. If you get an answer, I am interested in what you find.

Comment: I knew it was something stupid I missed. The script deployment was set to inactive. Change made by another user by mistake. Now I am getting triggers for validate line etc. thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Validate Line event is a client side event while the Before Load event is server side. You can't trigger client side functions from server side functions.

Comment: Sorry need to clarify. The before load event is adding elements to the UI. I was asking if I could access those fields in client side events. Just as I can custom fields added to forms etc.

Answer (score 0):

Script deployment was set to inactive by another user.